# Was this a callback or reference?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl, supergirl-2015

In *Supergirl: Crisis on Earth X*, Kara gets into a fight with

> her villainous counterpart.

During this fight, she gains the advantage by bashing her fists together, creating a shockwave that stunned

> Nazi Supergirl.

The camera seemed to focus on this action, and it seemed significant insofar as it let Supergirl gain the advantage in what was otherwise an even fight. It definitively seemed like a continuity reference: “Look, this is what Kara has that makes her stronger.”

However, I’ve watched all the episodes of *Supergirl*, and don’t recall her ever using this technique. Was it a callback or reference to something? Something that occurred in another show, or in the comics? Or a reference to something that someone other than Supergirl did?

Comment: @Edlothiad -  I'll just edit in the tags.

Comment: The super-powered clap generating a shockwave is a pretty standard comic book occurrence for super-strong characters. I can't say for certain whether or not Supergirl has ever used it in the comics, but Superman certainly has, as well as other characters from both major companies.

Comment: @Patrick - Yes, I've seen the Hulk do it (for example). My suspicion here, given that it was the element that tipped a basically equal battle, and how the camera focused on it, was that it's referencing something that we're supposed to remember.

Comment: So very tempted to edit the title; "*Has Supergirl got the Clap?"*

Comment: Supergirl has a superclap; http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_V7b-lFpP1bc/TKRZf7T9ROI/AAAAAAAAB_A/C7KqV_wpdvI/s1600/Supergirl+V1+08-21.jpg and http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ieVE0uMV-FU/TW6wTHjKAvI/AAAAAAAAB4k/_HBwz084_Qw/s1600/Action%2B287%2B19%2B-%2BSupergirl%2B03.jpg

Comment: This one is powerful; http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-BAP1Rl_78SA/U_8Y45MTagI/AAAAAAAAfRE/SlKY5i1zh7o/s1600/REDL-34-1.jpg

Comment: Anything in the Arrowverse?

Comment: @Adamant - Dunno. Not watching it

Comment: @Adamant AFAIK that was the first time the clap was performed by anyone in the Arrowverse.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It was the first time, probably because it looks to be extremely expensive, and they got extra budget for the Crossover, so they went all out i guess. Presumably they didn't have that budget in the next Supergirl episode *Reign*, because Kara didn't use it against the eponymous character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a standard superhero power, they just never used it before.
Now, the immediately preceding "Would you care to step outside?" line?  THAT was a callback.

Comment: Right up there with hitting the ground to make a shockwave, and the good old superhero landing.